# Layover in CDG Enough Time for Customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, layovers

My girlfriend and I will be travelling from Cincinnati to Athens, Greece in the next few months. There will be a stop on the way to Athens at CDG in Paris. I'm assuming that I will have to pass through customs once arriving at CDG. However, my layover there is only 1 hour. Is this enough time to pass through customs and board my connecting flight?

Comment: Coming from the USA you will pass though immigration in Paris but customs (most likely) in Athens. Immigration is where they check and stamp your passport, customs where they (might) check your luggage for things you need to pay tax on.

Comment: Are you traveling on a single booking, or two separate ones?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica It will be two people on a single booking.

Comment: That a single ticket was issued for this layover indicates that the airline believes you can make the connection.

Comment: Looks like you're flying CVG-CDG-ATH flights operated by Delta/Air France. If you miss the 9:15 flight out of CDG because your incoming flight is late, stop by an Air France desk and they will just rebook you onto the 12:15 flight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hour can be really short, even if there are no delays on your flight from Cincinnati.

As a precaution, before landing in Paris, notify the flight attendant of the situation; tell them what is your next flight (number and destination) and ask them if they know what gate is your next flight, and if it is in the same terminal.

It might be possible that they will let you exit the plane before other passengers.

Remember, DON'T PANIC.

Anecdotal, the last time we went through CdG (from Montréal to Italy,2 3 years ago), it was a short layover and we were stuck at one checkpoint because they were understaffed; we ran like hell after that.

Answer (score 1):

I lost a layover in CDG having only 50 minutes to do it. Even though the first flight didn't arrive late, I got help passing fast through immigration (the staff came to help me while I was in the line) and I ran. The flight was Santiago (Chile) -> CDG -> Amsterdam. All flights operated by the alliance Air France - KLM.
That time Air France just gave me a seat in the next flight to Amsterdam.

Nowadays I no longer take such shorts layovers in CDG.

If possible, pay for a seat in the front of the plane in the flight Cincinnati to CDG and travel with basic hand luggage.

Comment: "That time Air France just gave me a seat in the next flight to Amsterdam." As they're obliged to. Also, you're entitled to €600 in compensation if you arrived in Amsterdam at least 3 hours later than you should have

Comment: @Crazydre Indeed, that's true. I won a demand of €600 (+accomodation +transfer +food) against Iberia for a delay. But in this case, flights between CDG and Amsterdam are so regular that I took next flight one hour later, which does not deserve a compensation. In the case of the OP, the amount in case of delay might be between €300 and €600.